# How to create a button in Adobe Flash CC that reverses to its original state

Tags: animation, adobe-flash, button

I have a button that plays an animation as soon as the mouse goes over it, and I want to know how can I have the animation play in reverse (back to its original state) as soon as the mouse goes off it?

My method for the button is;
I made a movie clip symbol and inside it i have a button symbol with another movie clip (With the animation) as the over state.

Still learning flash and I'm fairly new to it, so my method might be wrong.

Comment: As a general question: Why are you using flash?

Comment: You will have to learn some Action Script to achieve this effect in Flash. This video might help you out [Reverse or Rewind Timeline Animations Flash Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDLLRoT2fAg#t=272). You will also find help at [http://stackoverflow.com/](http://stackoverflow.com/) for coding. Also take a look at this thread: [ActionScript 3 Mouse Out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217491/actionscript-3-mouse-out).

Comment: @EddieA. I'm using it because I'm busy with a project for college, and using flash is required.

Comment: @AndrewH - I'll be sure to give it a look. I thought that i might have to use some Action Script, so thank you for the links, will help a lot.